# Como verificar se a marcação do documento é HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, validação

Estou criando um plugin e preciso saber se o documento é escrito em HTML5 ou não.

Pensei em usar o `document.doctype`, mas não estou sabendo com o que compara-lo visto que compara-lo com `'<!DOCTYPE html>'` retorna falso, pois o mesmo é um nó e não texto.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou transformar o objeto em uma string ?

```
var objSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
var doctypeName   = objSerializer.serializeToString(document.doctype);

console.log(doctypeName);
```

Daí depois você pode fazer a comparação.

```
if(doctypeName == "<!DOCTYPE html>"){
    console.log('É HTML 5');
}
```

Comment: Beleza, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que documentos em HTML5 são declarados no bloco logo no início com: `<!DOCTYPE html>`, além deles existem as versões antigas conforme demonstrado nesse endereço:

https://www.totalvalidator.com/support/doctypes.html

Se em regra, o documento HTML5 não recebe versionamento, significa que se ouver uma **systemId** ou uma **publicId** declarada em seu bloco e que seja diferente de: `SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat"`. E que este documento contém um tipo de doctype definido por `<!DOCTYPE html>` ou `<!doctype html>`, podemos fazer a seguinte verificação:

```
 function checkHTML5() {
    var isHtml5 = document.doctype.nodeName;
    var systemId = document.doctype.systemId;
    var publicId = document.publicId;
    var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var doctypeHTML   = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(document.doctype);
    var doctypeName   = doctypeHTML.toLowerCase();
            if (isHtml5 == "html"                            &&
               (systemId == undefined                        ||
                systemId.indexOf("about:legacy-compat")!==-1 ||
                systemId == '')                              && 
                publicId == undefined                        ||
                publicId == ''                               &&
                doctypeName.indexOf("!doctype") !== -1) {
               return true;   
            }
    console.log(publicId);
    return false;
}
checkHTML5();
```

Comment: Testei aqui no console no próprio pt.so e não deu certo, retornou `false`...

Comment: Realmente havia um erro, pois a saída `systemId` pode ser tanto vazia como `undefined`, isso depende das definições do doctype, mas obrigado por me avisar do erro.

Comment: Agora ficou certo.. :)